# MySQL: Check if first character is _not_ A-Z

Tags: mysql

I have to create an SQL Query to get all rows starting with a specific character, except if the parameter passed to the (PHP) function is 0, in that case it should get every row that does *not* start with A - Z (like #0-9.,$ etc).

What is the easiest and fastest way to get those rows?

DB: MySQL 5.1
Column: title

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    mytable
WHERE   title NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE theColumn RLIKE '^[^A-Z]'
```

**Explanation**:
With RLIKE predicate, a bracketed pattern stands for any one character listed within the bracket (allowing for the use of a dash to indicate ranges, as here, A-Z is "A through Z").
Note the two ^ characters; they have a very distinct meaning:
The first one stands for "beginning of string"
The other ^ character, within the brackets indicates that the pattern should match any character which is *not* listed thereafter in the bracketed list.
See the [**mySQL documentation on pattern matching**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/pattern-matching.html) for more details.

The  could also be alternatively written as follow

```
...
WHERE theColumn NOT RLIKE '^[A-Z]'
```

**A word of caution**: Independently of the bracketed syntax, the patterns shown above both use a "front end wildcard", which can only be processed by way of a table/index **scan** (or for the least a partial scan) and this can be relatively inefficient with bigger tables.

Comment: In regular expressions, `%` is not a wildcard

Comment: @Quassnoi: good catch.  I mixed LIKE and RLIKE syntax...  All fixed, now.